# Hidden field leaves blank space

Tags: ios, ios6

When I hide a field programmatically, it leaves a blank space like this:

[image]

How can I make all the bellow fields move up to fill in the blank space? Also when I make the hidden field visible, all the fields bellow it should move down to the room for that field.

This is how I am hiding the TextField:

```
[self.txtFieldEmail setHidden:YES];
```

Comment: what code are you using to hide it programmatically?

Comment: @doublesharp | update my OP

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it yourself. You could use a table view and turn town on and off (but the indexing could be complex). Or you could implement `layoutSubviews` in your container to lay everything out when the configuration changes. Either way, you need to maintain the state and logic to do it. You may be able to find a 3rd party solution on GitHub...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is my 2nd day on iOS and I am "amazed" to see that we need to code for such obvious things. We need to code to hide the keyboard on blur of the fileds and we even need to code to adjust the element after one of them is hidden. This is very strange :-(

Comment: Any code made for UI has to be complex. Most GUI libraries on mobile and desktop platforms require to clearly specify where to locate tour views and its subviews. I really suggest that you try `UITableView` as @Wain said. If you have fey components in your view, the indexing won't be a problem.